# Add method call in test name with Unroll using Spock

Tags: groovy, spock, unroll

I have a code and I want to put method invocation value in the name of the method.

```
        @Unroll
        def 'check #file other text'() {
        setup:
        def file = allProperties.keySet().getAt(0)
        ...
        where:
        ...
```

Now I create special variable which purpose is only for naming the method. Can I do something like:

```
        static def allProperties
        def setupSpec(){
           allProperties== [1: 'asd', 2: 'ddd']
        }
        @Unroll
        def 'check #allProperties.keySet().getAt(0) other text'() {
        ....
        where:
        ...
```

Edited: Add setupSpec()

Comment: what good is naming your test there with something the actual test does not influence?  if this test later throws on me "check lerl other text", i would expect, that lerl somehow influenced the test and that it was part of the `where` thus the reason for the unrolling.

Comment: If I put it in Unroll the value of the file has to be the same for all places in the data table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Unroll` supports property access or zero-arg methods. So you can have:

```
@Unroll
def "check #allProperties.keySet().first() other text"() { .. }
```

provided `allProperties` is a class level variable or `@Shared` variable or mentioned under `where:` block.

Comment: Yes it is static, I tried what you say but the result is: "...Error:#allProperties.keySet().first.." but I initialize it in setupSpec() can that be the problem?

Comment: can you create a simple spec script replicating the problem? I can look into it.

Comment: You have to use `@Shared allProperties` instead.

Comment: With `@Shared` works, but what is the difference between Shared and static?

Comment: @Shared variables can be used in `where:` similar to static. But again I saw right now you are using assertion in `setupSpec` instead of instantiation. `allProperties ==  [1: 'asd', 2: 'ddd']`. Can you change it to `allProperties =  [1: 'asd', 2: 'ddd']` and use static instead of `@Shared`.

Comment: Refer docs for details. http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/index.html

Comment: and here is a doc section, with zero-arg specifics:  https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_unrolled_iteration_names